# Understanding why lsp-scala is not giving completions

Tags: lsp-mode

I have installed `lsp-mode`, `lip-scala`, `lsp-ui`, `company-lsp` and many other packages.   When entering scala code, I often get popups to complete the method/class/variable name, which also add the relevant imports if needed.

However, this does not always happen.  I am new to `lip-mode`, so I am not sure how to debug what is going wrong.  What are useful commands/settings to figure out what is going wrong when it is not working?

I have configured it with

```
;; lsp configuration
(use-package lsp-scala
  :after scala-mode
  :demand t
  ;; Optional - enable lsp-scala automatically in scala files
  :hook (scala-mode . lsp))
```

There are lots of messages in *lsp-log* but none of them indicate any obvious to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lsp-scala is deprecated and you should now use lsp-mode which has scala support via metals. From the lsp-scala repo:

> lsp-scala is now part of lsp-mode as lsp-metals. Please do not use this package.

I would suggest referring to the metals documentation which can help you with installation: https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/emacs.html (make sure you uninstal lsp-scala first).

## Useful command for debugging

What I usually do when something is not working is setting `(debug-on-error t)`, this will throw you into a debugger when there is an error and will enable you to start investigating where something went wrong.